# How to handle an inner query returning multiple values in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

How to handle an inner query returning multiple values in php mysql?

For eg.

`SELECT value1 FROM table1 WHERE value1 != (SELECT value1 FROM table2 WHERE .....)`

The problem is `(SELECT value1 FROM table2 WHERE .....)` is returning multiple values.

How to solve this?

Please help me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to use a subquery to limit the resultset of an outer query you can do that using `IN` or `EXISTS`

```sql
SELECT value1 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE value1 NOT IN 
(
  SELECT value1 
    FROM table2
   WHERE value1 IS NOT NULL ...
)
```

**Be careful with `NOT IN`** if subquery returns `NULL`s you won't get an expected result (an empty resultset). Either make sure that a subquery doesn't return `NULL`s (with appropriate `WHERE` clause or substitute `NULLS` with some value using `COALESCE` or `IFNULL`) or use `NOT EXISTS`

```sql
SELECT value1
  FROM table1 t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 
    FROM table2 
   WHERE value1 = t.value1 ...
)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2372c/3)** demo. *Note that the first query in the demo doesn't return any rows.*

**On the other hand** if you just need your subquery to return the only value

1) Use `LIMIT 1` as already suggested
2) or an appropriate aggregate function (`MIN(), MAX(), AVG()` etc)

```sql
SELECT value1 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE value1 <> 
(
  SELECT MAX(value1)
    FROM table2
   WHERE ...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Put "limit 1" at the end of your inner query.  This will tell the query engine to only return the first result.

But if you *want* to compare your value against multiple results in the subquery, use peterm's solution.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT value1
FROM table1
WHERE value1 != (
    SELECT value1 FROM table2 WHERE ... LIMIT 1
)
```

But make sure that subquery returns exactly what you need. Because since it returns multile values instead of one, you probably have some logic misunderstoods.

Also, if you need value1 to not equal several parameters instead of one, you can use `NOT IN`

```sql
SELECT value1
FROM table1
WHERE value1 NOT IN (
    SELECT value1 FROM table2 WHERE ...
)
```